# Omnifunc doesn't trigger after a few uses

Tags: neovim, lsp, ins-completion

I use omnifunc with the neovim built in LSP functionality and this is my configuration.

```lua
local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
vim.opt.completeopt = { "longest", "menuone", "popup" }

local servers = { "rust_analyzer", "pyright", "lua_ls", "clangd" }
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
    lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    }
end

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', {
    group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('UserLspConfig', {}),
    callback = function(ev) 
        vim.bo[ev.buf].omnifunc = 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc'

        local opts = { buffer = ev.buf }
        vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", vim.lsp.buf.definition, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "gr", vim.lsp.buf.references, opts)

        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>i", vim.lsp.buf.implementation, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>rn", vim.lsp.buf.rename, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, opts)

        -- Hover shows information about symbol like type
        vim.keymap.set("n", "K", vim.lsp.buf.hover, opts)
        -- Diagnostics show the errors only
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>D", vim.diagnostic.open_float, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "[d", vim.diagnostic.goto_prev, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "]d", vim.diagnostic.goto_next, opts)
    end
    }
)
```

The current behavior is that after I trigger omnifunc a few times with `<C-x><C-o>`, it will eventually just stop working. Meaning no matter how many times I input `<C-x><C-o>` the menu won't appear. I need to quit neovim, and open a file again then and only then I can use omnifunc.

I uploaded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGJ44_ii4k4) to YouTube showing this problem. The problem shows up around 0:40.

I expect to be able to use `<C-x><C-o>` and the menu will show up consistently. Instead of only being able to use it a few times before I need to restart neovim.

Comment: If it only depends on time/tries I suppose it is either a problem in the LSP bridge or in the LSP server itself. I believe you'll have more chance to report a GitHub issues in one of these repositories. Maybe could you check if the `clangd` server is still running when you experience your problem.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt with the help of someone from the neovim IRC, they've identified the problem and gave me a solution.

Comment: Great! Feel free to answer your own question. It will probably help others :-)

Comment: I'll do that! @VivianDeSmedt was waiting for the person who helped me (seandewar) to give an explanation as to why it broke to begin with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with another [part](https://github.com/AlphabetsAlphabets/nvim/blob/wsl/lua/core/autocmds.lua) of my config which runs `filetype detect` in an autocmd. The fix was to simply not source it.

This is the answer given by seandewar

> filetype detection will set ft=c as it's a C file, which will reload the C ftplugin (which sets omnifunc to ccomplete)

This is an issue because in my config I set the value of `omnifunc` as something else.

```
vim.bo[ev.buf].omnifunc = 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc'
```

So, `filetype detect` will set `ft=c` and remove the value set in my config. So, when I first open a file to edit and check the value of `omnifunc` this is the output.

[image]

Which is exactly what I set it to be. After `filetype detect` is ran in the autocmd the value of `omnifunc` changes.

[image]

Because the value of `omnifunc` changes, I am unable to use it as I want. The fix is that I should remove the `filetype detect` command from the autocmd.